# Erro ao rodar app direto no device IOS

Tags: ios, mobile, swift, xcode

Tenho um app que roda perfeitamente no simulador, o mesmo já está assinado com minha conta de dev. Porém quando tento fazer o build para rodar em um device "físico" alguns erros acontecem, já tentei reinstalar as bibliotecas utilizadas pelo Pods e tbm tentei apagar a pasta DerivedData mas sem sucesso. O que poderia estar ocasionando esse erro?

Segue stack do erro:

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks
>   /Users/diego/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-hcjzjblytpxfyucbgwmphvetikwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/my-project.build/Debug-iphoneos/my-project.build/Script-615B2B9C4AAE04ED75B72A96.sh
>       cd /Users/diego/Desenvolvimento/project/my-project
>       /bin/sh -c /Users/diego/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-hcjzjblytpxfyucbgwmphvetikwt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/my-project.build/Debug-iphoneos/my-project.build/Script-615B2B9C4AAE04ED75B72A96.sh
>
> mkdir -p
>   /Users/diego/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-hcjzjblytpxfyucbgwmphvetikwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my-project.app/Frameworks
>   rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "-
>   .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers"
>   --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/diego/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-hcjzjblytpxfyucbgwmphvetikwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework"
>   "/Users/diego/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-hcjzjblytpxfyucbgwmphvetikwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my-project.app/Frameworks"
>   building file list ... done Alamofire.framework/
>   Alamofire.framework/Alamofire Alamofire.framework/Info.plist
>
> sent 1624660 bytes  received 70 bytes  3249460.00 bytes/sec total size
>   is 1624230  speedup is 1.00 Code Signing
>   /Users/diego/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-hcjzjblytpxfyucbgwmphvetikwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my-project.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework
>   with Identity iPhone Developer: Diego Augusto (4L5839GH78)
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign
>   720B129FDEA6BFFF9AF1810B80DB6BC0A7DED204 
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/diego/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-hcjzjblytpxfyucbgwmphvetikwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my-project.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
>   /Users/diego/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-hcjzjblytpxfyucbgwmphvetikwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my-project.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework:
>
> errSecInternalComponent Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, tive que apagar o conteúdo da pasta `Keychains`

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Keychains
```

Em seguida baixei os certificados e chaves novamente.